# Best Practice to Write Dataframe to Azure SQL Server Table?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to push data from a dataframe (DF) into a SQL Server table.  I did some research on this yesterday and came up with this.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"            -> "my_sql_server.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"   -> "my_db_name",
  "dbTable"        -> "dbo.my_table",
  "user"           -> "xxxxx",
  "password"       -> "xxxxx",
  "connectTimeout" -> "5", //seconds
  "queryTimeout"   -> "5"  //seconds
))

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(config)
```

The idea is from this link.

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases-azure.html#connect-to-spark-using-this-library

Everything works fine if I use the original DF headers, as ordinal positions for field names (_c0, _c1, _c2, etc.).  I have to have these field names in my table to make this work.  Obviously, that's not sustainable.  Is there a way to get the DF loaded into a table without matching header names (the order of the fields will always be the same in the DF and the table).  Or, is it better way to do this, like renaming the field names of the Spark DF?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

```
val newNames = Seq("ID", "FName", "LName", "Address", "ZipCode", "file_name")
val dfRenamed = df.toDF(newNames: _*)

dfRenamed.printSchema
```